# Program is not stopping on EOF

Tags: c, eof

Currently when I hit `ctrl+d` it keeps on printing `> ERROR` over and over again until I suspend the program (`ctrl+z`). I have tried various ways to fix this but it breaks the program in other ways.

```
int main()
{
    char *command;      
    char **parameters;  
    int status;     
    size_t buffsize = 0;    

    while(1)
    {
        command = NULL;
        printf("> ");

       getline(&command, &buffsize, stdin);

        command[strlen(command)-1] = '\0';

        parameters = tokenize(command);


        if (!strcmp(command, "exit"))
        {
            exit(1);
        }

        if (fork() != 0) 
        {
            waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            status = execvp(command, parameters);
            if (status == -1)
            {
                printf("ERROR\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        free(command);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Here is the fix. Thank you to jil

```
if(getline(&command, &buffsize, stdin)) == -1) {
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: At what point does your program check for EOF?

Comment: I have tried adding `if (command == EOF)' or `command == 0)' 'return 0' but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What does the tokenize() function do? Unless calling it modifies the string command, you end up passing the full command as execvp's first argument, where you should be passing the path to the executable.

Comment: Any time you use a library function like `getline`, it's important to read the section in the man page that describes the **return value**.

Comment: ... indeed to read the *whole* man page, even before you have trouble with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you should check for EOF then and act accordingly. `man getline` says:

> return -1 on failure to read a line (including end-of-file condition)

So try something like:

```
if (getline(&command, &buffsize, stdin) == -1)
    return 0;
```